# DatePickerDialog display year picker first

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, datepickerdialog

I want my DatePickerDialog as soon as it opens to display the list of years.

For example, when I show the dialog I see the calendar view:
[image: calendar_view]:

If I tap on the text "1900" the year view is shown:
[image: year_view]

I tried this code but it had no effect and I'm clueless for what I could do:
`DatePickerDialog birthDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, 0, 0, 0);
        birthDatePicker.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
        birthDatePicker.show();`

Comment: So silly that it doesn't have an option to show the year view first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Datepicker XML modifications you can elect to show spinners instead of the Calendar, which might be beneficial for you as you want to directly edit the years.

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```

Answer (score 8):

Same as [Show year selection first in Android Calendar View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477118/show-year-selection-first-in-android-calendar-view/46223200#46223200)

I will copy here my answer:

> You can get a reference to year view and then just simulate user click to open it.

```
dataPicker.getTouchables().get( 0 ).performClick();
```

Comment: It is very useful. Thanks.