# Android: how to open datapicker fragment from year

Tags: java, android, datepicker, fragment

Hello i have write this class for implement a datapicker on android app:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {...
```

Can i set year picker when datapicker was opened?

Like this : https://i.vgy.me/iXYOjA.jpg

Now when datapicker was opened it start from a month and day picker

Like this: https://i.vgy.me/4FbZz8.jpg

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169584/datepickerdialog-display-year-picker-first

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, it work